# Error in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

my program is giving error

```
Sub my()

Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 8
    For j = 1 To 4
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) <> Sheet2.Cells(j, 1) Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(j, 2)
        End If      
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

it gives an error object required 
can someone tell me what is wrong in it i am new in VBA

Comment: Try Worksheets("Sheet1") instead of Sheet1 and the same for Sheet2

Comment: Based on the snippet, either `Sheet1` or its property `Cells` is missing, I would guess - or you've tried to reference a cell that doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you mean to use `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` as sheet `CodeNames` ?

Comment: Hey guys thanks it working but i am getting wrong output    like if my sheet had data 
a 
b 
c 
d 
e 
f 
g and my sheet two has data  
a  100 
b  100 
e  100  
f  100  so i should get data substitute for a b e and f only but i getting a 100
b 100
c 100
d 100
e 100
f 100
g 100
h 100
 kindly tell me whats wrong in code

Comment: it is substituting value in b column of sheet 1 whether value matches to sheet 2 or not

Comment: Don't you mean `If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(j, 1) Then` ?  i.e. when the value in column A of the two sheets **match**, copy the value of column B in Sheet2 to column B in Sheet1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

For i = 1 To 8
    For j = 1 To 4
        If ws1.Cells(i, 1) <> ws2.Cells(j, 1) Then
            ws1.Cells(i, 2) = ws2.Cells(j, 2)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```